# Replace & with &amp while Downloading xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, header

I am creating xml file like this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','ISO-8859-1'); //virsion of xml file
        $doc->formatOutput = true; // we want a nice output
        $data = $this->Story->getListOfAllStoryId(); //get all the story id by genrating url
        foreach ($data as $res) 
         {
            $root = $doc->createElement('url');
            $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

            $title = $doc->createElement('loc');
            $title = $root->appendChild($title);

            $text = $doc->createTextNode('http://escaplan.com/Story/story?story=' . str_replace(" ","_",$res['Story']['story_title']) . '?&strId=story_by_' . $res['Story']['id'] . '_Jhdy12kksi'); //adding coutry name to ulr only to xml file

            $text = $title->appendChild($text);
        }


        echo 'Wrote: ' . $doc->save("sitemap.xml")  // creating sitemap.xml file in root dir 
        $file='sitemap.xml';
        file_put_contents($file, str_replace('&amp;', '&', file_get_contents($file))); //replaceing all &amp; with & and saving the xml file 
        header('Content-Type: application/xml');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=sitemap.xml'); //downloading xml file
```

But when the user download the file it doesn't replace &amp with &.

Comment: htmldecode() htmlencode() ?

Comment: So, you basically want to intentionally make your XML invalid, do I get that right?

Comment: @Boldewyn Actually i want  to submit this file to webmaster tool. if i not replace &amp with & my  url will not work

Comment: @Dave where i should use htmlencode()???

Comment: If you break the XML like that, it will not work anywhere. The `&amp;` is the encoded version of an `&`. The XML parser will decode it.

Comment: @Thw  Actually i want to submit this file to webmaster tool. if i not replace &amp with & my url will not work so what is solution for that ??????

Comment: Have yo tried it? View the file in your webbrowser, you will see only &. You try to fix something that is not broken.